# Implementation of tanh() activation function for a CNN

Tags: c++, eigen, activation-function

I'm trying to implement the activation function tanh on my CNN, but it doesn't work, the result is always "NaN". So i created a simple application where i have a randomized matrix and try to apply the tanh(x) function thus to understand where's the problem?

Here's my implementation :

```
    Eigen::MatrixXd A = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(10,1000);
    Eigen::MatrixXd result, deriv;
    result = A.array().tanh();
    deriv = 1.0 - result*result;
```

and the only result to this is this error :

```
no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘double’ and ‘const Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0>’)
     deriv = (1.0 - result*result );
              ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Could you please help me ?

Comment: So your code is trying to assign a matrix to a scalar value? That's not going to work.

Comment: Can you give me a solution to this please? The input is a Matrix of weights so i'm obliged to use Matrix

Comment: I don't have a solution, a matrix and a scalar are two different things. I'm not sure what you expect to happen.

Comment: There's broadly speaking nothing "wrong" with calling `tanh` on a matrix, but the result is going to be a matrix as well. (Formally matrices belong in the domain of linear algebra and `tanh` doesn't, but you're probably abusing a matrix class to store an image)

Comment: thank you @MSalters it was a useful comment. I did that, and then there's another error : 
no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘double’ and ‘const Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0>’)
     deriv = (1.0 - result*result );
              ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: you can't do sum or substration between scalar and matrix.... (hint : deriv should be a matrix too)

Comment: Yes, i thought to make an eigen matrix of ones ... but didn't find how ? I find how to do it with Eigen::MatrixXd::Zeros and Eigen::Matrix::Identity but not with ones ...

Comment: @SabrinaTesla: You might want to read up on `auto`; you can let expression type determine variable type. Still, that won't allow you to do the mathematically impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product `result*result` does not have the right dimensions for a matrix multiplication. We can use `result*result.transpose()` instead (unless a coefficient-wise multiplication is intended, in which case one could use `result.array()*result.array()`).

To subtract the values of the resulting matrix from a matrix full of ones, the `.array()` method can be used:

```
deriv = 1. - (result*result.transpose()).array();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used **openCV** to create a matrix of ones 
like this :

```
cv::Mat sum;
Eigen::MatrixXd SUM, Acv;
cv::eigen2cv(A,Acv)
sum=Mat::ones(Acv.rows,Acv.cols, CV_32FC1);
cv::cv2eigen(sum,SUM);
```

so  :

```
deriv = SUM - result*result;
```

and now, here's another problem :(

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseBinaryOp.h :110 : Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<BinaryOp, Lhs, Rhs>::CwiseBinaryOp(const Lhs&, const Rhs&, const BinaryOp&) [with BinaryOp = Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<double, double>; LhsType = const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; RhsType = const Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0>; Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<BinaryOp, Lhs, Rhs>::Lhs = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<BinaryOp, Lhs, Rhs>::Rhs = Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0>]:  l'assertion « aLhs.rows() == aRhs.rows() && aLhs.cols() == aRhs.cols() » a échoué.
```

Comment: The problem that you are facing now is due to the wrong dimensions in the matrix product `result*result`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @RHertel, i did that and it works on my test.cpp, but now, i implemented this to my CNN's code, and there's a little problem :(

Comment: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseBinaryOp.h :110 : Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<BinaryOp, Lhs, Rhs>::CwiseBinaryOp(const Lhs&, const Rhs&, const BinaryOp&) [with BinaryOp = Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>; LhsType = const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; RhsType = const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<BinaryOp, Lhs, Rhs>::Lhs = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<BinaryOp, Lhs, Rhs>::Rhs = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]:  l'assertion « aLhs.rows() == aRhs.rows() && aLhs.cols() == aRhs.cols() » a échoué.